How to Install Firefox from Official Mozilla Repository on Ubuntu 24.04
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and would like to install Firefox directly from the official Mozilla repository instead of the default Ubuntu Snap/PPA repositories.

To install Firefox from the official Mozilla repository on Ubuntu 24.04, follow these steps:

Install the repository key:
wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O- | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.gpg > /dev/null


Create a deb822-formatted .sources file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.sources with the following content:
Types: deb
URIs: https://packages.mozilla.org/apt
Suites: mozilla
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.gpg


Set the apt repository priority by creating/editing the file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla with the following content:
Package: firefox*
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1001


Allow unattended upgrades for the mozilla repository by creating/editing the file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox with the following content:
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern { "archive=mozilla"; };


Remove the snap and apt installation of Firefox:
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo apt remove firefox


Update the package list:
sudo apt update


Install Firefox from the Mozilla repository:
sudo apt install firefox


(Optional) Install additional translations with the packages firefox-l10n-XX where XX is the language identifier (e.g. firefox-l10n-it for Italian).
sudo apt install firefox-l10n-XX



By following these steps, you should have Firefox installed from the official Mozilla repository on your Ubuntu 24.04 system.
